# Terraform iterate over map for each of count resources

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform module that creates N EC2 instances using "aws_instance" and count (set to N).

I'm now trying to tag the primary ENIs for the instances with a list of tags. I have come up with the below working solution, but is there a cleaner/better way?

```
    resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ec2_eni" {
      count = (length(aws_instance.this[*]) * length(local.tags))
    
      resource_id = aws_instance.this[count.index % length(aws_instance.this[*])].primary_network_interface_id
      key         = keys(local.tags)[count.index % length(local.tags)]
      value       = values(local.tags)[count.index % length(local.tags)]
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: No, it works. Ultimately I'm probably going to just create the ENIs w/ tags then attach to the EC2 instances. Using "aws_ec2_tag" should be mostly relegated to items managed outside of TF according to the documentation. Being relatively new to TF I'm just trying to understand if there is a simpler way using a "for" expression or some function. Thank you.

Comment: Your are not using `"for" expression` in your code. The common issue with `count` is that it relays on order of items. So changing order of tags or instances will require re-genearation of all tags.

Comment: The modulo trick is pretty good, IMHO. Terraform has a lot of trouble creating structures that require nested loop like behavior. A cleaner setup would require refactoring into modules and looping over those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation like this I'd typically prefer to construct a data structure that fits with the expectations of [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) and then  work with that, which can then avoid the need to do arithmetic with indices.

Although you didn't show `resource "aws_instance" "this"` I assume it also has a `count` argument and so `aws_instance.this` is a list of instance objects. That means these instances will be uniquely identified only by their positions in that list, which is appropriate if they are all interchangeable, but that does mean that our `for_each` expression must produce unique keys that include those indices:

```
locals {
  instance_tags = flatten([
    for idx, inst in aws_instance.this : [
      for key, value in local.tags : {
        instance_idx = idx
        interface_id = inst.primary_network_interface_id
        tag_key      = key
        tag_value    = value
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ec2_eni" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for it in local.instance_tags :
    "${it.instance_idx}:${it.tag_key}" => it
  })
    
  resource_id = each.value.interface_id
  key         = each.value.tag_key
  value       = each.value.tag_value
}
```

This will declare `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni` instances with addresses like this (assuming two instances and a tags map containing `Name` and `Component` tags):

- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["0:Name"]`
- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["0:Component"]`
- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["1:Name"]`
- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["1:Component"]`

A key advantage of this approach is that if you add a new element to `local.tags` later -- let's call it `Environment` for example -- then Terraform will be able to see that it needs to create the following two new addresses:

- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["0:Environment"]`
- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["1:Environment"]`

...whereas with the index-arithmetic approach you tried, it's likely to create a far more disruptive plan because the calculated indices will no longer refer to the same tag names.

Adding a new instance can have a similar effect, with Terraform resolving it as the need to create only the new tags for that instance:

- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["2:Name"]`
- `aws_ec2_tag.ec2_eni["2:Component"]`

In other words, this design makes it explicit to Terraform that each tag is uniquely identified by one instance index and one tag index, which allows it to better understand the intent of adding, removing, or updating instances and tags.